# How does the Healer feat actually work?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

So, the feat actually says this:

> • As an action, you can spend one use of a healer’s kit to tend to a
>   creature and restore 1d6 + 4 hit points to it, plus additional hit
>   points equal to the creature’s maximum number of Hit Dice. The
>   creature can’t regain hit points from this feat again until it
>   finishes a short or long rest.

So, let's say I do this on a lvl 4 cleric. Would he heal 1d6+4+4 (because he has 4 Hit Dice) or 1d6+4+8 (because his maximum value of a hit die is 8)? Can anyone please explain it to me?

Comment: For anyone's interest, the only reason it is worded that way is so it does healing on creatures. It could be simplified to "the target's level". But all creatures have hit dice, but only PCs have levels.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's the number of hit dice the receiving creature has. For each hit die it gets a single hit point more.

An Orc having one hit die would get 1d6+4+1, while a human fighter level 6 would get 1d6+4+6.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is in the text you quoted -

> plus additional hit points equal to the creature’s maximum number of Hit Dice

So, in your example, 1d6+4+4.

Note that the extra healing is based on Maximum number of Hit Dice, rather than current number of Hit Dice.